# Why do people encourage to have more classes in java when more objects means more time for implementation?

Tags: java, oop, memory-management

I know that it is more time consuming to find an object in the heap than in stack. And I have also seen that people advising to create more classes for different tasks. May be the code can be more understandable and clean if there are more classes. But,what about the time? can anyone please explain that to me.

Comment: A lot of other things mean more time for implementation too. Don't think in one dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Object-oriented programming means more separation of concerns and a good segregation of concepts.

It tries to address problems closer to how our mind works. Real world has uncountable objects and things. Each one has a definition and properties, and also behaviors.

Clearly object-oriented programming may use more memory and even CPU power, but more than 2 decades ago everyone thought that, once computer raw power and memory were increased every year, optimization was still important but **productivity became the priority**.

There're still some corner cases where object-oriented programming isn't the answer, but almost any business or home-use application in the world is developed using object-oriented programming because companies want to ease maintanability and be able to respond to change in a meaningful and productive way (**to do more and reduce costs**).

Answer (score 0):

Your code, more often than not, will be a solution to a problem. The number of classes isn't something that you predetermine. It depends on the complexity of the problem to be solved and the complexity of its solution. If the raison d'etre of your code is just to find the nth fibonacci number and nothing else then the code may reside in just a single class(or none at all) but if your code is, say, an enterprise software designed to tackle a complex problem like banking then there are many factors that decide your design and thereby the number of classes. Two of the biggest factors are maintainability and extensibility of your code.

You should have a look at the [SOLID](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.PrinciplesOfOod) principles for Object Oriented design, first named by Robert C. Martin.

Once you go through them and more on OO design I hope "more classes vs less classes" won't be a question for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a decision being made in order to boost performance, being the difference irrelevant at runtime IMHO. Neither I think the developing time is going to differ a lot. I think what it's important to understand here is [the Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). So I think the criteria isn't "create more classes" but "do not use the same class for two different things", (what in the end makes you create more classes, but isn't the same).

What I've realized on the time I've been working is that, while the system grows up, the most important thing is **how it does it**. If you create less classes you will end up with 30k lines classes that are completely impossible to debug efficently. The same applies with 400 lines methods doing 20 different things. This means **a lot of extra time wasted** as adding new functionalities and fixing existing ones become more and more complex. In the end you need to apply a certain criteria to separate your code and avoid ending up on tha situation and the Single Responsibility Principle seems a good one.